# UITextfield bouncing text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I set inset for text field

```swift
class PrimaryTextField: UITextField {

    var padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)

    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

}
```

It works well, but text is bouncing, when user is jumping between textfields.

[image]

Problem is appearing only on real devices, the simulator is OK. Don't you have any ideas, how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were problem with keyboardWillHide and show notifications. I animate constraints there. I add code below before animations and text is not bouncing anymore.

```swift
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
        emailTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
        passwordTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Comment: Fixed my problem

Comment: This was a fix for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can create `IBInspectable UITextField`

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + padding, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - padding * 2, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + padding, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - padding * 2, height: bounds.height)
    }
}
```

It is working for me in iOS Device too.

can you please try and let me know.

Comment: Hey, still same problem.